# Taking an webpage element with Jsoup in AsyncTask in a fragment (Android Newbie)

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, jsoup

I'm new to Java and Android so I need your help. 
I've implemented JSoup in my app to take this from a webpage and show it in a textview (I'm operating in a fragment but i think it's the same as a standard activity in this case).

```
<body marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
<h1></h1>
<p class="testoprezzo">0.5516 </p>
</body>
```

I've to take only 0.5516

I have no idea on how to do it. Can you help me? 
This is the code I've already written:

```
class fetcher extends AsyncTask<Void,Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

        try {

            String value = "https://mywebpage.net/";
            Document document = Jsoup.connect(value).followRedirects(false).timeout(30000).get();
            Element p= document.select ("p.testoprezzo").first();
            ((Globals)getApplication()).setValore(p.text());




        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);


        TextView valore = findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        valore.setText(((Globals)getApplication()).getValore());








    }
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [Elements](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html) to get the **p** tag.

```
class fetcher extends AsyncTask<Void,Void, Void> {
String txtValue;

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

    try {

        String value = "https://mywebpage.net/";
        Document document = Jsoup.connect(value).followRedirects(false).timeout(30000).get();
        Element p= document.select ("p.testoprezzo").first();
        txtValue = p.text();




    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        txtValue = null;
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);


    TextView valore = findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    valore.setText(txtValue);
}
```

}

Please see that **Elements** and **Element** are different. Use them as per your need.
Here is the list of all [selectors](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) along with example.

Also note: **DON'T DO ANY U.I. CHANGE** in `doInBackground` method, or else you will get an error.

Comment: I've tryed,but Android Studio don't resolve the method ''select'' in Element p= document.select("p").first();

Comment: make sure you are importing something like this `import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;` in import section and not the other ones.. there are 3 -4 type of documents available depending on your project.

Comment: Just last question,how to bring the value of the result String to a textview? I tryed onPostExecute but seem work differently in a fragment

Comment: Declare a global string variable and on `doInBackground` assign that value of `p` to your string variable, then in `onPostExecute` method write this line `yourTextView.setText(your_string_variable_name);`

Comment: Uhm...for some reasons it don't work,but i can't figure why,the application go,but the text don't come out

Comment: Nope,simply the taken text don't come out in runtime,maybe i can try with a webview?

Comment: update the question with the latest code.. and post also log trace if you see any error

Comment: it is because there is no value set for that variable

Comment: declare a variable like `String yourString;` after Asynctask and then set the value in doInBackground and then set the textView value as your string variable

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the most restrictive selector as you can, in order not to get irrelevant results. In your case you should use -

```
Element e = doc.select("p.testoprezzo").first();
String result = p.text();
```